# Can Cloudflare workers be used for heavy traffic?

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, bandwidth

I tried to find the details about traffic limit on Cloudflare workers, the only limit I found is by the number of requests.

Can I use it to provide extremely heavy traffic 10, 20, 30, 50, 100, or 1000 TB/month?

I'm trying to find any ToS for workers but no luck... Can I use them for codec critical video that I don't want Cloudflare to transcode via their stream service? Can I use it to serve images? or other large files?

What are the limitations to avoid "hurting" the service and other users that may be sharing same resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Technically speaking,** Workers have no problem with serving 1000 TB/month and trillions of requests. You will not see any performance degradation at such traffic levels, nor will it negatively impact other users. The limit on requests that you mentioned only applies to the free tier.

**Legally speaking,** the supplemental Terms of Service for Workers are found here:

https://www.cloudflare.com/supplemental-terms/#CFWorkers

Per the first item, there are no restrictions on image content. However, there is still a restriction on video content. You will need to use Cloudflare Stream or sign an enterprise contract to serve video.

Comment: Thank you! that's the answer I needed. contacted CF sales, they were unable to give such a clear answer or link to the relevant ressource.

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely proxy heavy traffic through Workers, but, if you try to cache or serve content like videos, (excessive amounts of) photo/audio or other large files, then that may violate Section 2.8 of Cloudflare's ToS and result in a hold on your account: https://www.cloudflare.com/terms/

This is something to bear in mind as a self-serve customer. Cloudflare determines what's "non-HTML content" by inspecting the content-type header of the incoming request. However, enterprise customers can have more leniency on this front.

P.S. If you meant "heavy traffic" to include RPS, then Workers scales well with a spike in requests like the CDN.

Comment: Hey! thanks a lot for your answer, Yes I meant serving videos through workers. In this post https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=20790857, eastdakota (CF's CEO) mentioned that workers do have different ToS, and said using it for heavy images is ok so the section 2.8 does not apply to workers probably, but the limits are still unclear... that's why I'm asking about videos...